# ignore fields while comparing two lists

Tags: collections, java-8

I have two lists of Person objects.

```
Person class has the below attributes
String Name, 
Integer Age, 
String Department, 
Date CreatedTime,
String CreatedBy
```

When I compare my lists for equality, I would like not to compare the CreatedTime and CreatedBy fields.

How can I compare, using Java 8, the two lists for equality and also ignore the CreatedTime, CreatedBy fields for comparison?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need features from Java-8 to do this, simply override the `equals` & `hashCode` like this:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    String department;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (name != null ? !name.equals(person.name) : person.name != null) return false;
        if (age != null ? !age.equals(person.age) : person.age != null) return false;
        return department != null ? department.equals(person.department) : person.department == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (age != null ? age.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (department != null ? department.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you can compare two given lists like so:

```
 boolean result = firstList.equals(secondList);
```

**edit:**

following your comment:

> I need this form of comparison only for test purposeses . In my
>   production code I would like to retain equals and hashcode to compare
>   all fields

you can define a custom equal method like so:

```
public static boolean areEqual(List<Person> first, List<Person> second) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(first, "first list must not be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(second, "second list must not be null");
        return first.size() == second.size() && 
                IntStream.range(0, first.size()).allMatch(index -> 
                        customCompare(first.get(index), second.get(index)));
}
```

or if you want to allow null to be passed to the `areEqual` method then a little change will suffice:

```
public static boolean areEqual(List<Person> first, List<Person> second){
        if (first == null && second == null)
            return true;
        if(first == null || second == null ||
                first.size() != second.size()) return false;

        return IntStream.range(0, first.size())
                        .allMatch(index -> 
       customCompare(first.get(index), second.get(index)));
}
```

then along with it the method that will determine if two given person objects are equal:

```
static boolean customCompare(Person firstPerson, Person secondPerson){

        if (firstPerson == secondPerson) return true;

        if (firstPerson.getName() != null
                ? !firstPerson.getName().equals(secondPerson.getName()) : secondPerson.getName() != null)
            return false;

        return (firstPerson.getAge() != null ? firstPerson.getAge().equals(secondPerson.getAge()) : secondPerson.getAge() == null)
                && (firstPerson.getDepartment() != null
                ? firstPerson.getDepartment().equals(secondPerson.getDepartment())
                : secondPerson.getDepartment() == null);
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
boolean result = areEqual(firstList, secondList);
```

Comment: I need this form of comparison only for testing purposes . In my production code i would like to retain equals and hashcode to compare all fields

Comment: @megan The method names provided may not be the best but I'll leave that to you to modify as you please. :)

Comment: @megan doing this sort of thing for test purposes is very very common! A good test framework will give you an easy way to implement these sorts of things - might I recommend AssertJ. The above code is of course correct; but doing something like this every time you need to compare things is going to add a lot of noise to your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Streams.zip()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) from Guava for a more functional solution. Ignoring `null` checks for brevity:

```
public static boolean comparePersonLists(List<Person> list1, List<Person> list2) {
    if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    return Streams.zip(list1.stream(), list2.stream(), (a, b) ->
        a == b || (a.name.equals(b.name) && a.age.equals(b.age) && a.department.equals(b.department))
    ).allMatch(t -> t);
}
```